# How to subtract two datetimes and check if it is less than 12 hours in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I need to subtract currentdate/time with a datetime attribute and check if it is less than 12 hrs.

```
IF currentdate/time - check datetime < 12 hrs
    print("Wait period is 12 hrs")
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `java.time` types try `ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startDate, endDate)`. Alternatively you could use `startDate.until(endDate, ChronoUnit.HOURS)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use *java.time* classes.

[`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time not attached to the timeline on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime then = ZonedDateTime.of( 2021 , 3 , 18 , 15 , 30 , 0 , 0 , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now ) ;
if( d.toHours() < 12 ) { … }
```